# jQuery how to search for an element at a given index or later

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html of basically

```
<div class="letter">A</div>
<div class="letter">B</div>
<div class="letter"></div>
<div class="letter">D</div>
<div class="letter"></div>
```

and a jQuery function that is returning the index of the first empty div (with the class "letter")

```
var firstEmptyIndex;

var findStart = function(){
    var firstEmptyElement = $('div.letter:empty:eq(0)');
    firstEmptyIndex = firstEmptyElement.index('div.letter');
}
```

How can I extend this findStart function to pass a variable that will begin searching for an empty element at a given index. For exmaple, I want to run findStart(3), which would return the index of the fifth element in the HTML example (4). Running findStart(0) or findStart(1) would return 2.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Comment: PeeHaa's answer is exactly what you need. I've deleted my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `:gt` and `:first`:

```
var findStart = function(i){
    return $('div.letter:gt(' + i + '):empty:first').index('div.letter');
}
```

Comment: I think you should `return $('div.letter:gt(' + i + '):empty:first').index('div.letter');`

Comment: @raina77ow I focused on the selector and didn't notice that. Changed as per Vega's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of JQuery's [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, which, in one form, allows you to pass a filtering function that takes in your index. So, the following should work:

```
someResultSet.filter(function (i) { return i < someOtherIndex; })
```

Answer (score 0):

[`slice(start[,end]`)](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method or [`:gt(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery's filter method to return just the elements without text.

```
var selector = ".letter" ;
$(selector).filter(function(){return !$(this).text()}).get(0) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will work 
it returns null is no empty elements are found.
other wise it will return next empty element index

```
var findStart = function(n){
    var i=n-1,l=$('div.letter').length;
    for(;i<l;i++){
        if($('div.letter').eq(i).html()==""){
            return i;
        } 
    }
    return null;
}
```